# What tense should we use when referring to a paper or experiments from other researchers?

Tags: writing, writing-style, literature-review

While writing the literature review section, I am confused about which tense should I use (past, present perfect, or present) while referring to other people's work.

I understand that established facts are presented in the present tense.
Work done is presented in past or present-perfect tense.
But in what tense should I define their (i) system model, (ii) experiments, and (iii) results so that the overall picture remains coherent and it does not seem like I am jumping from one tense to another?

What is the basis for using any of these tenses?

Answer (score 5):

I present established facts in present tense, indeed. Other people's work that has led to these facts is presented in past or present-perfect. So for example: "Snippert et al. *established* a confetti mouse-line, and after doxycyclin administration *showed* that intestinal crypts *tend* towards clonality."

Comment: To do this, you do need to know what counts as an 'established fact' and what is just the latest theory. The history of science is littered with 'established facts' that no-one now believes. The Greek word hubris describes the attitude summarised thus: "Back then they thought X, but now we know Y". In truth Y is just the latest theory; it could be overturned tomorrow. These thoughts suggest to me that a sprinkling of "generally accepted" and such-like phrases would be prudent.